# 'React way' to instruct a child component to scroll to an element

Tags: javascript, reactjs

We have developed the following pattern in our React application.

```
this.setState({secondaryViewerSelectedAnnotationId: annotationId}, () => {
  this.secondaryViewer.scrollToSelectedAnnotation();
})
```

With `scrollToSelectedAnnotation` exposed from `Viewer` component via `useImperativeHandle`.

Me not being React-native, it feels a bit odd to separate "scrollToX" into two operations. I start wondering about race conditions (don't laugh at me, I'm from Java!) E.g. if after setState runs but before the callback is executed there is another action (triggered either by the user or by the backend), `this.setState({secondaryViewerSchmoopsId: schmoopsId}, () => { this.secondaryViewer.scrollToCurrentSchmoops(); })`. Or even a major model change (`this.setState({secondaryViewerData: completelyNewData})`) which would make the previous `annotationId` irrelevant.

###### The question

Is the approach above (`setState` with a callback, or its functional component equivalent) the idiomatic way to implement "selectXAndScrollToIt" behaviour in React? Or is there a better approach?

One alternative is to expose "selectXAndScrollToIt" with `useImperativeHandle`, but it seems to be not very React-ey:

```
this.secondaryViewer.selectAnnotation(annotationId);
```

---

For context, I'm aware there are similar questions around, but they tend to deal with a single component, not a parent-child api. Many of them are also are prone to 're-scrolling', e.g. they will call `this.selectedAnchor.scrollIntoView()` in `componentDidUpdate` on every rerender from now till the end of times.